# How do I target the link color, within a navbar, when hovering in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css

I am styling a navbar using CSS to modify the .navbar-inverse within Bootstrap 3.

My current HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle hvr-glow" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My Sites
   <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank">CodeSandbox</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I want the to change the color of the link tag that says "My Sites" when I hover over it. Currently, when I hover the link it changes to the same color as the background, which is the color that the other links are supposed to be when hovered over... I do not want to change the hover effect of the other links.

My current CSS for the navbar is:

```
#banner{
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand{
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #FDFFFC !important;
    background-color: #011627 !important;
}

.navbar-brand:hover{
  color: #E71D36 !important;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: #011627 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

.navbar-nav a{
  color: #FDFFFC !important;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover{
  color: #2EC4B6 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #FF9F1C !important;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover{
  color: #011627 !important;
  background-color: #FF9F1C !important;
}

.dropdown-toggle{
  background-color: #2EC4B6 !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
  color: #011627 !important;
}
```

Picture:

[CSS next to my page. I am hovering the link that I cannot target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFzZH.png)

Comment: I see that all your css code uses `!Important`, is everything really important?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am super new, and still in school. I thought that I needed to use !Important to override Bootstrap's built in CSS.

EDIT: Just tested it, and if I remove the !Important, then the CSS does not apply.

Comment: I have solved this problem with the help of some classmates! The selector for this is:

.navbar-nav a.iWantThisOne:hover{
  color: #011627 !important;
}

I added a class to the anchor tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this?

```
.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

and obviously change red in the hover to whatever color you want. Also you should only really use `!important` when its necessary, even for bootstrap where it is used a lot, you seem to be using it a little too much.